# AvalonDock MVVM dynamic view

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism, avalondock

I am using the AvalonDock from the Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock package (version 3.5). The docking manager is part of my main view. The interesing part is here:

```
    <xcad:DockingManager Name="_dockingManager" Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding DockingManagerViewModel}"
                     DocumentsSource="{Binding Documents}"
                     AnchorablesSource="{Binding Anchorables}" >

        <xcad:DockingManager.Resources>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DockingWindowViewModel}">
                <v:SampleDockWindowView />
            </DataTemplate>

        </xcad:DockingManager.Resources>

        <xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type dockctrl:LayoutItem}" >
                <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}" />
                <Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{Binding Model.CloseCommand}" />
                <Setter Property="CanClose" Value="{Binding Model.CanClose}" />
            </Style>
        </xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>

    </xcad:DockingManager>
```

So the main view model contains an observable collection (e.g. "Documents") where I can add view models dynamically. The problem is now that I have different views for the different view models and the views will be added during runtime. Currently the views are retrieved based on the data templates:

```
    <xcad:DockingManager.Resources>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DockingWindowViewModel}">
            <v:SampleDockWindowView />
        </DataTemplate>

    </xcad:DockingManager.Resources>
```

How can I change this to get a dynamic view based on the corresponding view  model?

Comment: You can use a [`DataTemplateSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=netframework-4.8) to implement more complex template selection logic.

Comment: @BradleyUffner: This doesn't really help. I do not want to do a complex selection I want to add a dynamic view. Not sure if I understand this correctly

Comment: By "complex", I simply mean "more than what can be done statically in 
XAML". You want to determine which template to display from a list of templates supplied dynamically at runtime.  You could build `Dictionary<Type, DataTemplate>` at runtime that you use to map types to templates, and the `DataTemplateSelector` can just return the template registered for that type.  This allows you do add / remove templates at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

As some people already answered here, you need to add a template selector.
So an example may drive you.

Supposing you have 2 couple of view/viewmodel named

`MyDocViewA -> MyDocAViewModel`

`MyDocViewB -> MyDocBViewModel`

On the main view XAML code, within you `DockingManager` code, you need to add a `LayoutItemTemplateSelector` like this:

```
                <xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
                <s:PanesTemplateSelector>
                    <s:PanesTemplateSelector.MyDocViewATemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <p:MyDocViewA />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </s:PanesTemplateSelector.MyDocViewATemplate>
                    <s:PanesTemplateSelector.MyDocViewBTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <p:MyDocViewB />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </s:PanesTemplateSelector.MyDocViewBTemplate>                        
            </xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
```

Where `s` is the namespace where you define the `PanesTemplateSelector` as following:

```
    class PanesTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate MyDocViewATemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate MyDocViewBTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is MyDocAViewModel)
            return MyDocViewATemplate;

        if (item is MyDocBViewModel)
            return MyDocViewBTemplate;
    }
}
```

Assuming that `MyDocAViewModel` is the `ViewModel` for view `MyDocViewA` and `MyDocBViewModel` is the `ViewModel` for view `MyDocViewB`.

That's it. Now you can add instances of `MyDocAViewModel` and `MyDocBViewModel` to your observable collection (eg. "Documents") of your `DockingManager` and get it bindinded to `MyDocViewA` and `MyDocViewB` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

View to view model is normally a one-to-one mapping, so just add a lot of `DataTemplate`s... either from xaml or from code or a combination of both (a xaml per module and code in the modules initializer to merge the module's `ResourceDictionary` into that of the app).

Comment: Perhaps then DataTemplate is not the right "tool" to handle this. Any ideas how I can avoid this???

Comment: Data template is _the_ tool if you want to define a view for a view model. If you don't like to have lots of one-liner data templates, I suggest you scrap your user controls and define the view directly in the data template.